# Como puedo mostrar una foto en flutter la cual es traída del api de Laravel, pero este campo contiene varias url

Tags: laravel, flutter, webapi

Deseo mostrar una img en flutter pero en la base de datos MySQL guarde en un array en la cual estén las rutas que acceden a las img como podría utilizarlas en flutter.
[image: Base de datos]
[image: Posman]

Comment: podrías empezar leyendo la documentación oficial : https://flutter.dev/ , empezar a entender widgets, consumo de apis, peticiones asíncronas, luego de eso ya podrás resolver lo que mencionas.

Comment: de lo del widgets si le cacho pero como convierto del formato que me trae de la base de datos a un String para poder mostrar la img

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, en laravel deberías obtener una url no el path donde esta esa imagen, para ello hay diferentes métodos en la documentación.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-urls

o por defecto puedes hacer esto:

1. Recoges el primer link del array
2. En ese archivo cambias storage por public y añades la url de tu api de laravel.
   Quedaría tal que así:

   [www.myurlLaravel.com/public/ofertas/...](http://www.myurlLaravel.com/public/ofertas/...).

Con esa url deberías de poder pintar la imagen.